# Bootstrap affix within column

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So my site has a fixed header 90 px and I need to implement another fixed div that sits inside a col-md-8 and when scrolling it stays right under the fixed header. I used affix for that and it works fine, the fixed part, however, the width is all messed up. If I add 100% width to the div and then I inspect it, the div container STARTS from where the col-md-8 does, however it spans to the end of the page itself and not to the end of the column. I posted my current the code below. Any idea on how to get a fixed div to stay inside of a bootstrap column and use the same width of the column?

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="affix" data-spy="affix" style="z-index: 1">
                         <div>
                              <img src="" class="img-responsive"/>
                         </div>
                         <div>
                              <img src="" class="img-responsive"/>
                         </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This is the layout I am going for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/svZ0n.jpg

Any information and help is welcomed!

EDIT: I have a working solution (see below), however, I am sure someone has a better version/solutions for my problem.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(setAffixWith);
        $(window).resize(setAffixWith);

        function setAffixWith() {
            var colWidth = $('.col-md-8').width();
            $('.affix').css('width', '' + colWidth + '');
        }
    </script>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0" style="z-index: 1">
                <div class="fixed-toggle">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <img src="" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <img src="" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

.fixed-toggle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Could be great to create FIDDLE or add CSS..

Comment: I don't have any custom css for this code, just plain bootstrap.